# XML error on while loop (php, xml element)

Tags: javascript, php, xml, loops, while-loop

As the title suggests i've had some trouble creating an xml element using php. The document runs fine without my while loop (loop through mysqli_fetch_assoc and print xml for all results) but when i run it inside the while loop i get the following error

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 3 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the >document
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I have tried moving the header around a bit but the only thing that has accomplished is getting the xml to run as simple text(no styling or structure), while giving me some js errors on the browser log.
I need help in finding out what the nature of the error is and why it is happening.

Below is my php code:

```
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
session_start();
require_once 'somefile';

$_SESSION['usr'] = 55;

$date = date("Y/m/d h:i:s");

$datetime = $date;

$m = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM 
    some_table WHERE some_condit = someother_condit");
while($main = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m)) {
$propid = $main['id'];  
$s = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tabletwo WHERE tableid = 
'$propid'");
$e = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tablethree WHERE tableid = 
'$propid'");
$i = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM imgtable WHERE img_table_id = 
'$propid'");
$side = mysqli_fetch_assoc($s);
$extr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($e);
$img = mysqli_fetch_assoc($i);
$titleGR = 'Ακίνητο: '.$extr['brokerListingID'].' || 
'.$extr['propertyType'];
$titleEN = 'Listing: '.$extr['brokerListingID'].' || 
'.$extr['propertyType'];
if($main['prop_type'] === 'residential') {
    $ECAT = 6;
}else if ($main['prop_type'] === 'commercial') {
    $ECAT = 7;
}else if ($main['prop_type'] === 'land') {
    $ECAT = 8;
} else {
    $ECAT = 15;
}
if($extr['garage'] === '0' || $extr['garage'] === '1') {
    $garage = 0;
} else {
    $garage = 1;
}
if($extr['storageSpace'] === '0' || $extr['storageSpace'] === '1') {
    $storage = 0;
} else {
    $storage = 1;
}
if($extr['balcony'] === '0' || $extr['balcony'] === '1') { 
    $Balc = 0;
} else {
    $Balc = 1;
}
if($extr['airConditioning'] === '0' || $extr['airConditioning'] === '1') {
    $air = 0;
} else {
    $air = 1;
}
if($extr['secureDoor'] === '0' || $extr['secureDoor'] === '1') {
    $door = 0;
} else {
    $door = 1;
}

if($extr['alarm'] === '0' || $extr['alarm'] === '1') {
    $alm = 0;
} else {
    $alm = 1;
}
if($extr['newDevelopment'] === '0' || $extr['newDevelopment'] === '1') {
    $new = 0;
} else {
    $new = 1;
}
if($extr['fireplace'] === '0' || $extr['fireplace'] === '1') {
    $fire = 0;
} else {
    $fire = 1;
}
if($extr['swimmingPool'] === '0' || $extr['swimmingPool'] === '1') {
    $swim = 0;
} else {
    $swim = 1;
}
if($extr['elevator'] === '0' || $extr['elevator'] === '1') {
    $extr['elevator'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['elevator'] = 1;
}
if($extr['playroom'] === '0' || $extr['playroom'] === '1') {
    $extr['playroom'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['playroom'] = 1;
}
if($extr['garden'] === '0' || $extr['garden'] === '1') {
    $extr['garden'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['garden'] = 1;
}
if($extr['petsAllowed'] === '0' || $extr['petsAllowed'] === '1') {
    $extr['petsAllowed'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['petsAllowed'] = 1;
}
if($extr['furnished'] === '0' || $extr['furnished'] === '1') {
    $extr['furnished'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['furnished'] = 1;
}
if($extr['awning'] === '0' || $extr['awning'] === '1') {
    $extr['awning'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['awning'] = 1;
}
if($extr['airy'] === '0' || $extr['airy'] === '1') {
    $extr['airy'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['airy'] = 1;
}
if($extr['view'] === '0' || $extr['view'] === '1') {
    $extr['view'] = 0;
} else {
    $extr['view'] = 1;
}
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<Estate/>');
$ID = $xml->addChild('ID', $main['id']);
if($main['spito'] === '0') {
    $status = $xml->addChild('Status', '2');
} else {
    $status = $xml->addChild('Status', '1');
}
$SendDate = $xml->addChild('SendDate', $datetime);
$UpdateDate = $xml->addChild('UpdateDate', $datetime);
$Title_GR = $xml->addChild('Title_GR', $titleGR);
$Title_EN = $xml->addChild('Title_EN', $titleEN);
$Description_GR = $xml->addChild('Description_GR', $side['prop_desc_gr']);
$Description_EN = $xml->addChild('Description_EN', $side['prop_desc_eng']);
$Aim_ID = $xml->addChild('Aim_ID', $main['prop_ad_type']);
$EstateCategory_ID = $xml->addChild('EstateCategory_ID', $ECAT);
$EstateSubCategory_ID = $xml->addChild('EstateSubCategory_ID', $DEV);
$Price = $xml->addChild('Price', $main['prop_price']);
$SqrMeters = $xml->addChild('SqrMeters', $main['prop_m2']);
$Area_ID = $xml->addChild('Area_ID', $extr['geographyId']);
$Prefecture_ID = $xml->addChild('Prefecture_ID', $extr['geographyId']);
$Region_ID = $xml->addChild('Region_ID', $extr['geographyId']);
$ConstuctYear = $xml->addChild('ConstuctYear', $main['prop_year']);
$Floor_ID = $xml->addChild('Floor_ID', 999);
$Levels = $xml->addChild('Levels', $main['prop_level']);
$BedRooms = $xml->addChild('BedRooms', $main['prop_rooms']);
$Parkings = $xml->addChild('Parkings', $garage);
$StorageRoom = $xml->addChild('StorageRoom', $storage);
$Balcony = $xml->addChild('Balcony', $Balc);
$HeatType_ID = $xml->addChild('HeatType_ID', 999);
$AirCondition = $xml->addChild('AirCondition', $air);
$SecureDoor = $xml->addChild('SecureDoor', $door);
$Alarm = $xml->addChild('Alarm',$alm);
$StreetAccess_ID = $xml->addChild('StreetAccess_ID', 1);
$EnergyClass_ID = $xml->addChild('EnergyClass_ID', 2);
$Orientation_ID = $xml->addChild('Orientation_ID', 999);
$NewBuild = $xml->addChild('NewBuild', $new);
$Bathrooms = $xml->addChild('Bathrooms', $main['prop_bath']);
$Kitchens = $xml->addChild('Kitchens', $extr['kitchens']);
$Fireplaces = $xml->addChild('Fireplaces', $fire);
$Pool = $xml->addChild('Pool', $swim);
$Elevator = $xml->addChild('Elevator', $extr['elevator']);
$Playroom = $xml->addChild('Playroom', $extr['playroom']);
$Garden = $xml->addChild('Garden', $extr['garden']);
$Loft = $xml->addChild('Loft', 0);
$PetsAllow = $xml->addChild('PetsAllow', $extr['petsAllowed']);
$Furnishing = $xml->addChild('Furnishing', $extr['furnished']);
$Safe = $xml->addChild('Safe', 0);
$Latidude = $xml->addChild('Latidude', $extr['latitude']);
$Longitude = $xml->addChild('Longitude', $extr['longitude']);
$Tents = $xml->addChild('Tents', $extr['awning']);
$Boiler = $xml->addChild('Boiler', 0);
$FloorType_ID = $xml->addChild('FloorType_ID', 999);
$Video = $xml->addChild('Video', $extr['virtualTourURL']);
$Video360 = $xml->addChild('Video360', $extr['virtualTourURL']); 
$URL3D = $xml->addChild('URL3D', $extr['virtualTourURL']);
$Diamperes = $xml->addChild('Diamperes', $extr['airy']);
$NearToSchool = $xml->addChild('NearToSchool', 1);
$NearToBus = $xml->addChild('NearToBus', 1);
$TennisCourt = $xml->addChild('TennisCourt', 0);
$Gym = $xml->addChild('Gym', 0);
$Concierge = $xml->addChild('Concierge', 0);
$Grass = $xml->addChild('Grass', 0);
$Blinds = $xml->addChild('Blinds', 1);
$Dishwasher = $xml->addChild('Dishwasher', 1);
$SpaHotTub = $xml->addChild('SpaHotTub', 0);
$CCTV = $xml->addChild('CCTV', 0);
$Refrigerator = $xml->addChild('Refrigerator', 1);
$Washingmachine = $xml->addChild('Washingmachine', 1);
$View = $xml->addChild('View', $extr['view']);
$RampForDisabled = $xml->addChild('RampForDisabled', 0);
$Landscaping = $xml->addChild('Landscaping', $extr['view']);
$RVParking = $xml->addChild('RVParking', $garage);
print($xml->asXML());
}
```

Putting the header just below the print gives the correct results but with no styling and with a number of js errors (plus weird formating, text all over the window).
Any help that will get me closer to the resolution of this matter will be greatly appreciated, ty in advance!

Comment: A XML document should have no styling.  It sounds like you are jamming HTML together with XML and (rightfully so) getting some errors.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem. In this case, that means you remove the database code, start with simple array inputs, and create a minimal XML file.